# Подменю скрывается при опускании указателя ниже первого пункта

Tags: html, css, меню

Не понимаю почему так происходит... есть меню с подпунктами. При наведении на пункт меню, показываются подпункты. Но если пускаться по подпунктам ниже первого подпункта, подменю исчезает.

Кто-нибудь может подсказать в чем дело?

Спасибо заранее!

```css
.menu-wraper {
  max-width: 70%;
}

.menu-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px auto;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

.menu-list {
  max-height: 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.menu-list>li {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
  margin-right: 15px;
}

.menu-link {
  font-size: calc(20px + (32 - 20) * ((100vw - 992px) / (2250 - 992)));
  color: slategray;
}

.menu-link:hover {
  color: rgb(165, 207, 250);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(165, 207, 250);
}

.menu-sublist {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  padding: 15px;
  width: 300px;
  height: fit-content;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-sublist li {
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
}

.menu-sublist li:last-child {
  margin: 0;
}

.menu-sublink {
  font-size: 24px;
  color: slategray;
  z-index: 10;
}

.menu-sublink:hover {
  color: rgb(165, 207, 250);
}

.menu-arrow {
  display: none;
}


/* ----------------------- */

.menu-list>li:hover .menu-sublist {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  pointer-events: all;
}

.menu-list>li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-link {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.menu-arrow {
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 10px;
  transition: transform 0.3s ease 0s;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid slategray;
}

.menu-list>li._active .menu-sublist {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(0px, 0px);
  pointer-events: all;
}

.menu-list>li._active .menu-arrow {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}

.menu-list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.menu-list>li {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.menu-sublist {
  transform: translate(0px, 10%);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu-body">
  <ul class="menu-list">
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link fa-solid fa-house"></a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link" id="visual">l'art visuel</a>
      <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
      <ul class="menu-sublist">
        <li>
          <a href="https://google.com/" class="menu-sublink">peinture</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-sublink">sculpture</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-sublink">photographie</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-sublink">cinéma</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">littérature</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">événements</a>
      <span class="menu-arrow"></span>
      <ul class="menu-sublist">
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-sublink">rallyes</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="menu-sublink">actions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" class="menu-link">publications</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="menu-link">à propos</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: предположу, что выходит из области родительского li. Дочернее подменю не плотно прилегают к родительскому и при переходе hover  пропадает. Но код не очень работоспособный - плохо понятно как все должно задумано.

Comment: Сделал форматирование вашего кода, и тут все работает, есть вероятность что какието дополнительные стили портят размеры области подменю, или допустим на странице есть элементы которые перекрывают меню

Comment: @ТёмаKornishon, мне тоже кажется, что что-то перекрывает нижние элементы подменю, но что никак не могу найти...

Comment: @Arbery, подменю прилегает плотно - я могу навести указатель на первый (верхний его пункт). Проблема возникает при дальнейшем движении указателя вниз, к нижним пунктам подменю

Comment: Правой кнопкой на родительский пункт меню (допустим événements), нажать "просмотреть код" найти li этого элемента, в вкладке "стили" кнопку :hov, там выбрать :hover. Теперь откроется пункт на постоянку, далее ctrl+shift+c и поводить над выпадающим меню мышкой. Будет ясно что перекрывает

Comment: Спасибо, @ТёмаKornishon! Подменю перекрывала плашка с иконками соцсетей (в моем коде здесь ее нет)